# Dash Multiple Page Application With Callbacks

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I created a couple dash applications and now I think I'd like to connect them with a menu that takes you between the pages.

So i used this example: https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps/tree/master/apps/dash-financial-report to begin however, each page in my application has specific callbacks associated and those callbacks need a dash app defined to work. How can I make this example work with callbacks with pages that have callback calls inside them? (i.e. I'd like to keep the header portion as on every page as I move through).

https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/dash-financial-report/overview